# Jenkins plugin manager - need to update the password under the proxy settings, by command

Tags: jenkins, passwords

I am trying to update the password under "manage jenkins -> manage plugins -> advanced -> HTTP proxy configuration's password field". I am trying to write a script to implement this password update, insted of doing it manually through the Jenkins UI. Is there any groovy/pythin/bash command/script that i can implement, in order to update this password by automation?

Comment: How is the password change frequency? And how jenkins could get the new password for an automation?

Comment: the frequency is once per 3 months;    we have a user named 'Jenkins_system' which is managed under a safebox, and is used for the proxy configurations.  the password for this user is changed as described here. therefore, i would like to update the 'password' field accordingly, under the 'http proxy configuration' page that is under the advanced tab in 'manage plugins'